# How can I run bash script file from chef-recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I want to implement the logic in chef-recipe like below. How I can achieve this

```
File=/tmp/productMain.param
if [ -f "${File}" ]; then
 if [ -f /tmp/monitor.sh ]; then
     echo "[INFO] configuration beeing processed"
     /tmp/monitor.sh $File
 else
    error "The monitor script doe not exit
    exit 1
 fi
else
  error "input file does not exist"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Did you even try yourself ? SO is not a free code service

Comment: Hi Tensibai,
Thanks for your quick reply.I am new to Ruby language.. 
file=ProductMain.param
cookbook_file "/temp/monitor.sh" do
  source "monitor.sh"
  mode 0755
end

execute "config Agent" do
  command "sh /tmp/monitor.sh #{file}"
end

please correct this..

Comment: [edit] your post,and be kind to others, this is not a paid support. We help on our free time. See notifications on http://docs.chef.io

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Chef documentation, it is very good and gives examples on how use the bash resource: https://docs.chef.io/resource_bash.html

Comment: Thanks Wim and buruzaemon, for your quick reply.I am new to Ruby language.. 
file=ProductMain.param
cookbook_file "/temp/monitor.sh" do
  source "monitor.sh"
  mode 0755
end

execute "config Agent" do
  command "sh /tmp/monitor.sh #{file}"
end

please correct this..